# PyQt5 Печать HTML документов

Tags: python, html, pyqt5, qwebengineview

Друзья, кажется, я обыскал весь интернет, но так и не нашёл, какие сейчас есть способы печати **`HTML`** документов в *PyQt5* ?

Раньше можно было использовать `QtWebKitWidgets.QWebView`, но теперь убрали возможность печати `HTML` с помощью этого класса.

Может кто поделиться кодом для печати `HTML` страниц?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предварительный просмотр <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> и
печать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -`QWebEngineView` в PyQt5

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QEventLoop, QObject, 
    QPointF, Qt, QUrl, pyqtSlot)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrintDialog, QPrinter, QPrintPreviewDialog
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QLabel, QProgressBar, \
    QProgressDialog, QShortcut


class PrintHandler(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.m_page = None
        self.m_inPrintPreview = False

    def setPage(self, page):
        assert not self.m_page
        self.m_page = page
        self.m_page.printRequested.connect(self.printPreview)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def print(self):
        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        dialog = QPrintDialog(printer, self.m_page.view())
        if dialog.exec_() != QDialog.Accepted:
            return
        self.printDocument(printer)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def printPreview(self):
        if not self.m_page:
            return
        if self.m_inPrintPreview:
            return
        self.m_inPrintPreview = True
        printer = QPrinter()
        preview = QPrintPreviewDialog(printer, self.m_page.view())
        preview.paintRequested.connect(self.printDocument)
        preview.exec()
        self.m_inPrintPreview = False

    @pyqtSlot(QPrinter)
    def printDocument(self, printer):
        loop = QEventLoop()
        result = False

        def printPreview(success):
            nonlocal result
            result = success
            loop.quit()
        progressbar = QProgressDialog(self.m_page.view())
        progressbar.findChild(QProgressBar).setTextVisible(False)
        progressbar.setLabelText("Wait please...")
        progressbar.setRange(0, 0)
        progressbar.show()
        progressbar.canceled.connect(loop.quit)
        self.m_page.print(printer, printPreview)
        loop.exec_()
        progressbar.close()
        if not result:
            painter = QPainter()
            if painter.begin(printer):
                font = painter.font()
                font.setPixelSize(20)
                painter.setFont(font)
                painter.drawText(QPointF(10, 25), "Could not generate print preview.")
                painter.end()


def main():
    import sys

    QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("Previewer")

    view = QWebEngineView()
    view.setUrl(QUrl("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207961"))
    view.resize(1024, 750)
    view.show()

    handler = PrintHandler()
    handler.setPage(view.page())

    printPreviewShortCut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_P), view)
    printShortCut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.CTRL + Qt.SHIFT + Qt.Key_P), view)

    printPreviewShortCut.activated.connect(handler.printPreview)
    printShortCut.activated.connect(handler.print)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ого! Спасибо, это отличное решение)

Comment: Но, вопросик, как быть с потерей качества? Ведь, если я правильно понимаю, QPainter отрисовывает html документ. И при выводе на печать html файл получается несколько растянутым. В итоге, часть информации становится малопригодной для чтения.

Comment: @Chudvan  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-printme-example.html Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Chudvan если у вас возникают другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос.