# Qt свой QPrintDialog

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt5, принтер

Можно ли унаследоваться от `QPrintDialog`, к примеру, и создать свой кастомный виджет диалогового окна с настройками принтера и т.д.?

По умолчанию следующий код вызывает такое окно:

```
QPrinter printer;
QPrintDialog printWindow(&printer, this);
printWindow.exec();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А хотелось бы передавать ещё и изображение документа, который печатается, как, например, в пдф или ворде сделано, что-то типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для этого надо сделать свой какой-нибудь MyPrinterDialog.

Comment: Ответ на Ваш вопрос: Да, можно.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужен предварительный просмотр - 
 так? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207961/pyqt5-%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2/1207964#1207964